How can I restrict XR Origin movement on Unity?
I am developing a VR game on Unity now. And I have a problem controlling XR origin.
I would like to restrict XR origin (Main Camera) movement so as not to make the player go outside of the available area. However, I am not sure how to achieve this goal. Could anyone help me out?
Situation
Using XR origin on XR toolkit.
I am using a Teleportation System and Continuous Move Provider (Action-based) for the left controller.
Things I've tried:

Added Character Control to the main camera and set Box Collider on the side of the available zone.
Tried to restrict Transform.Position from the script.

Neither of these did not work.

In VR you can't really restrict a players movement - as you can't restrict their physical movement ... you can however use a trick and let the VR camera move slower the further away it gets from the XR origin (not sure of course if Unity supports this though) ... as your title stands I think the XR origin you pretty much control yourself so that one you can definitely restrict

How about installing walls around a player? In my Unity, XR origin goes through walls so the player can go anywhere. Is it possible to restrict player's movement by surrounding the player with walls?
